# after rebasing on a branch, how to update master to match that rebased branch?

Tags: git, git-svn, rebase

I've done a bunch of rebasing on a test GIT branch. The rebasing was done for two reasons: #1: to integrate changes in a parent git-svn trunk; #2: to clean up my local history in preparation for handing off the code to another developer.

I have my test branch the way I want it, all tests are passing, etc. Now I want to make master look just like my test branch.

What's the preferred way to do this?  If master weren't there already, I'd just `git clone` it, but is there another better way to force an existing branch to look just like anohter (including history)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deleting the branch and recreating it where you want it does work, but it costs you your reflogs - the record of where the branch has pointed in the past. The two cleaner ways:

```
# if you want the branch checked out:
git checkout master
git reset --hard <other-branch>

# or, if it's not checked out:
git branch -f master <other-branch>
```

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to make a branch look like another (including history) is to just create a new branch.

The `master` branch is just another branch (git simply sets that to be the default when initializing a new repository, but you are free to set your own default branch).

If I understand you correctly, just delete the `master` branch and create a new branch called `master` using the `test` branch.

Comment: I don't think this is the proper way at all. It costs you your reflogs. Don't delete and recreate, just reset. `git checkout master; git reset --hard <other-branch>`. Or, if you don't want to check it out, `git branch -f master <other-branch>`.

Comment: @Jefromi - this sounds like the right answer... if you want to break it out of a comment into a standalone answer, I'll accept it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

What I do is merge my work branch into *my* master branch (it has my initials prefixed).  Then I push that master, which the one-committer reviews and merges into the real master.

so the answer is, merge, i think